# Ускорение парсинга данных aiohttp + async

Tags: python, парсер, асинхронность, распараллеливание, aiohttp

Здравствуйтe, имеется код:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import os
import time
import logging
import lxml.html
from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector as cssselect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO)

limit = asyncio.Semaphore(10)  #Количество одновременных запросов


url_test = []

#Асинхронный метод для отправки http-запросов
async def request(client, url):
    global limit
    with await limit:
        async with client.get(url) as r:
            print(r.status)
            return await r.text()

#Асинхронный метод преобзования ответа от сервера в дерево DOM
async def get_html (request):
    # return lxml.html.fromstring(request)
    return BeautifulSoup(request, 'lxml')



async def main_page(client, url):
    t_start = time.time()
    r = await request(client, url)
    html = await get_html(r)
    t_end = time.time()
    log.info("Time End: %s", t_end - t_start)



async def main(urls):
    """
    Создет группу сопрограмм и ожидает их завершения
    """
    # создаем экземпляр клиента
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        # создаем корутины
        coroutines = [main_page(client, url) for url in urls]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines)
        for item in completed:
            result = item.result()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(100):
        url_test.append("https://aquapolis.ru/")
    log.info("Start")

    # получаем экзепляр цикла событий
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        # запуск цикла  обработки событий
        event_loop.run_until_complete(main(url_test))
    finally:
        # обязательно закрываем
        event_loop.close()
```

Для теста парсим 100 раз главную страницу, у меня занимает около 80 секунд (в 10 одновременных соединений), что я считаю очень долго.
Может кто-что посоветовать для увеличения скорости парсинга?
Версия python: 3.7

**Update:**
Имеется код:

```
results = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:

        coroutines_category = [request(client, url) for url in url_list_category]
        completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(coroutines_category)
        for item in completed:
            results.append(item.result())

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parsing_category, results):
            pass
```

Сначала мы собираем ответы от сервера асинхронно и добавляем в список.
После окончания сбора начинаем парсить страницы в потоках.

**Вопрос:** как можно сделать, чтобы при добавлении в список ответа от сервера, он сразу начал парситься? Тем самым мы потратим меньше время на парсинг, ведь CPU все равно не занят?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть возможность использовать Linux - я бы посоветовал использовать [uvloop](https://habr.com/post/282972/)

```
import asyncio
import uvloop
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
```

2. Для ускорения процесса Вам необходимо убрать парсинг страниц из курутин, так как bs4  не асинхронная библиотека и вы просто рушите всю логику работы. Попробуйте сначала скачать все, что нужно, а потом уже распарсить, например в многопоточном(процессорном) режиме
3. В версии 3.7 доступна функция [asyncio.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) которая берет управления loop'ом на себя.

Comment: а если использовать библиотеку lxml?

Comment: Или подскажите асинхронные быстрые библиотеки для парсинга на Python

Comment: а вы пробовали для своей задачи регулярные выражения?

Comment: @danilshik насчет lxml - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967103/beautifulsoup-and-lxml-html-what-to-prefer

Comment: Я имел ввиду lxml асинхронная или также синхронная?
Мне нужна максимальная скорость, идея со скачиванием страницы и только потом обработки - хорошая, но я не хочу занимать место на диске

Comment: @danilshik а кто говорил про диск? я имел ввиду Вы сначала получите данные с помощью aiohttp, например в список, а потом уже обработайте этот список с данными в многопоточном режиме с использованием bs4.

Comment: А количество потоков должно быть равно количеству ядер? Использую ThreedPoolExexutor

Comment: @danilshik лично я использую Pool из multithreading + функция map

Comment: Если мы сохраняем в списке, значит это все хранится в оперативной памяти. Если я сначала запрошу 60000 ссылок и сохраню их список, все будет упираться в оперативную память.

Comment: @danilshik а почему бы вам не запрашивать по 6000?

Comment: добавил обновление

Comment: @danilshik если Вам пригодился мой ответ - нажмите галочку) а то у Вас уже второй вопрос пошел..

Comment: не подскажешь с последним вопросом? внизу добавил

Comment: @danilshik Вы имеете ввиду, что вы хотите получать результаты из курутин сразу как он готов? я так не пробовал, но посмотрите вот тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456881/getting-values-from-functions-that-run-as-asyncio-tasks
А вы не думали просто меньше запросов делать за один заход, так бы результат получали быстрее.

Comment: С оперативной памяти все норм, протестировал